# Use ORDER BY in OVER clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I'm new to T-SQL and windowing functions.

I don't why below two queries produce same result:

```
SELECT 
    empid, ordermonth, val,
   SUM(val) OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY ordermonth
                  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS runval
FROM 
    Sales.EmpOrders;
```

and

```
SELECT 
    empid, ordermonth, val,
    SUM(val) OVER(PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY ordermonth) AS runval
FROM 
    Sales.EmpOrders;
```

Output is the same:

[image]

Isn't that the second query should produce the same total value for each empid? or is `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` the default and is optional when use order by in over clause?

Comment: That is the default (or it might be`RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` but they are the same in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For running sum (and similar) the difference is visible when there is a tie in `ORDER BY ...` between two rows. Consider this example where employee has two orders on `2006-09-01`:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (empid INT, ordermonth DATE, val INT);
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, '2006-07-01', 100),
(1, '2006-08-01', 100),
(1, '2006-09-01', 100),
(1, '2006-09-01', 100),
(1, '2006-10-01', 100);

SELECT empid, ordermonth, val,
   runval_rows = SUM(val) OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY ordermonth ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),
   runval_auto = SUM(val) OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY ordermonth)
FROM @t

empid | ordermonth | val | runval_rows | runval_auto
1     | 2006-07-01 | 100 | 100         | 100
1     | 2006-08-01 | 100 | 200         | 200
1     | 2006-09-01 | 100 | 300*        | 400*
1     | 2006-09-01 | 100 | 400*        | 400*
1     | 2006-10-01 | 100 | 500         | 500
```

When the row/range clause is not specified then SQL Server defaults to:

> If ROWS/RANGE is not specified but ORDER BY is specified, RANGE
>   UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW is used as default for window
>   frame.

And in most simple words, SQL server defines range* as the set of rows inside a partition that have identical values in columns specified in `ORDER BY` clause. So the second variant treats the 3rd and 4th as part of same range and includes both of them when calculating running sum.

* Be advised that this definition is different from the "standard" definition and the answer only applies to SQL Server.

Comment: could you have a look at this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107566/how-come-a-page-can-be-both-intent-shareis-and-intent-exslusiveix

Comment: Hi your answers are always concise and straightforward. Could you have a look at this question? Thanks a Million https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/241509/when-updated-records-get-written-to-the-real-physical-pages-in-mdf-file?noredirect=1#comment476336_241509

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same value for each `empid`, then do not use the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT empid, ordermonth, val,
       SUM(val) OVER (PARTITION BY empid) AS runval
FROM Sales.EmpOrders;
```

Otherwise, your two expressions are the same -- if the sort key is unique.  The default is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> If ROWS/RANGE is not specified but ORDER BY is specified, RANGE
>   UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW is used as default for window
>   frame.